# How can i add parameter inside the header of the API HTML request using android sdk

Tags: deezer

I want to add the X-DEEZER-IP-FORWARD parameter inside the  header of the HTML request.what should I do Using android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there's no way to add parameters inside the Header of a request when you use a DeezerRequest object.

Besides, the X-DEEZER-IP-FORWARD is a special parameter used only in specific applications, and would not be of any use in an Android Application.